# Como comunicar entre classes?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, classes

Estou iniciando no JavaFX e estou com dúvidas.

A classe principal cria um HBox com um botão. Esse botão tem a ação de criar uma `TableView` no Center da `bdPrincipal`. Só que estão em classes/packages diferentes.

Qual a melhor maneira de buscar a `bdPrincipal` pra adicionar a `addTabela()`?

```
BorderPane bpPrincipal;
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        bpPrincipal = new BorderPane();
        bpPrincipal.setLeft(Menu.addMenu());
        scPrincipal = new Scene(bpPrincipal);
        primaryStage.setScene(scPrincipal);
        primaryStage.centerOnScreen(); 
        primaryStage.setHeight(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getHeight()); 
        primaryStage.setWidth(Screen.getPrimary().getVisualBounds().getWidth());        
        primaryStage.show();
    }    


public class Menu {
    public static HBox addMenu() {

        HBox hbox = new HBox();
        hbox.setPadding(new Insets(15, 12, 15, 12));
        hbox.setSpacing(20);
        hbox.setStyle("-fx-background-color: #336699;");

        Button btnListar = new Button("Listar");
        btnListar.setPrefSize(100, 20);
        btnListar.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
            public void handle(ActionEvent evento) {
                  GestorFX.bpPrincipal.setCenter(addTabela());
            }
        });
        hbox.getChildren().addAll(btnListar);

        return hbox;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings({ "rawtypes", "unchecked" })
    private static TableView addTabela()
    {
        TableColumn colCodigo = new TableColumn();
        colCodigo.setText("Código");
        colCodigo.setMinWidth(150);
        colCodigo.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("clienteCodigo"));

        TableColumn colFantasia = new TableColumn();
        colFantasia.setText("Nome Fantasia");
        colFantasia.setMinWidth(450);
        colFantasia.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("clienteFantasia"));

        TableColumn colRazao = new TableColumn();
        colRazao.setText("Razão Social");
        colRazao.setMinWidth(450);
        colRazao.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("clienteRazao"));

        TableView tabela = new TableView();
        tabela.setItems(Negocio.Cliente.ListaCompleta());
        tabela.getColumns().addAll(colCodigo, colFantasia, colRazao);

        return tabela;
    }
}
```

Comment: O seu título não corresponde com a sua dúvida. Na verdade você quer saber como fazer as classes se comunicarem, certo? Além disso você também tem dúvida na criação do TableView? Por exemplo, se eles estivessem na mesma classe você saberia resolver o problema?

Comment: Sim, talvez a minha dúvida possa ser desmembrada. Vou alterar o título.

Comment: Ok. Só nao entendi uma coisa, você sabe então criar o TableView?

Comment: Sim, o TableView acredito que saiba, porém, a comunicação das classes é que estou com dificuldades.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basicamente você deve importar o pacote da outra classe e criar um objeto dela, sendo assim você conseguirá acessar seus métodos públicos.

Supondo que o seu primeiro código que possui um `BorderPane bpPrincipal;` esteja no seguinte arquivo:

> src\com\pacote\Paineis.java

Adicione o seguinte import dentro da sua classe Menu:

**Menu.java**

```
import com.pacote.Paineis;
```

Já é possível enxergar a classe, agora crie um objeto da classe Paineis, e acesse o método que desejar dessa classe. Exemplo:

**Menu.java**

```
Paineis paineis = new Paineis();
BorderPane bdPrincipal = paineis.getBpPrincipal(); //pronto
```

Agora use `bdPrincipal` como desejar, por exemplo adicionando-o na tabela.

Não se esquece de criar um método que retorne o BorderPane da sua classe Paineis:

**Paineis.java**

```
public BorderPane getBpPrincipal() {
        return bpPrincipal;
}
```